# Selenium - Failed to Establish New Connection

Tags: python, selenium

I'm following this tutorial and pasted the exact code from the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b5jt2bhSeXs

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "/home/matt/learnselenium/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://techwithtim.net")
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()

search = driver.find_element_by_name("s")
search.send_keys("test")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()
```

And I get the following error:

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=54375): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/efc07a083600a61c9bc65e262061dd37/element (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f254da226a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

I verified Chrome (94) and the Chrome driver are the same version
I have ./chromedriver running

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the `driver.quit()` line after `print(driver.title)`. You are closing the driver before complete execution.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it

Comment: @KamaleshS :  I think you should write that as an answer, so that OP can accept and system will mark this as an accepted answer. It's just an advise you can ignore as well.

Comment: @cruisepandey thanks for the suggestion!!

Comment: @KamaleshS : No problem !

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `driver.quit()` line after `print(driver.title)`. You are closing the driver before complete execution.